# Connect Nexus 7 to Android phone using ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am working on a interesting problem. I want to debug my android phone from my nexus 7 tablet.

I have managed to connect the two devices using USB cable and the nexus 7 is in host mode, however the phone is only recognized as a camera or a storage device.

I have terminal up and running on my nexus 7. I am running adb but cannot see the connected samsung s3 device.

Has anyone done something like this? Any ideas on what can be done here?

Thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: have you enabled debug option in nexus 7

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the same thing thru the [Terminalemulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm). I got the same results as you first, then I tried to pull the USB cables from the three intersections, and replacing it again:

1. in phone
2. between OTG and standard cable
3. in nexus 7

I got it to work when I pulled it out from the nexus 7 (host) and replaced it.

I have a rooted nexus 7 but it did not seem to need any su permisions. It also worked to put a USB hub between the two devices and add a keyboard so that the terminal operation was smoother.

I hope that you get it to work, it is a pretty cool feature!